# Recorrer un json descartando repetidos de forma óptima

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Imaginemos que tengo este json

```
var personas = [
    {name: "paco", edad:23},
    {name: "pepe", edad:25},
    {name: "lucas", edad:30}
]
```

Pero realmente tengo 1000 personas y quiero obtener todos los nombres de las personas y que no estén repetidos, puedo hacer un `for` para recorrer todos pero no se si hay alguna otra forma más rápido para no recorrer 1000 objetos

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Una forma facil y eficiente es primero ordenar el arreglo, y sacar los elementos unicos con solo un for

```js
var personas = [
    {name: "paco", edad:23},
    {name: "paco", edad:23},
    {name: "pepe", edad:25},
    {name: "paco", edad:23},
    {name: "lucas", edad:30},
    {name: "paco", edad:23}
];

var names = personas.map(function (person) { return person.name; });
var sorted = names.sort();

var unique = sorted.filter(function (value, index) {
    return value !== sorted[index + 1];
});

console.log(unique);
```

El ultimo elemento va a comparar con `undefined`, lo cual no importa porque van a ser distintos

Este algoritmo es `O(N * logN)` para ordenar y `O(N)` para sacar duplicados, por lo que es bastante rapido

Answer (score 3):

Esto te podría ayudar...

```js
    var personas = [
        {name: "paco", edad:23},
        {name: "paco", edad:23},
        {name: "pepe", edad:25},
        {name: "paco", edad:23},
        {name: "lucas", edad:30},
        {name: "paco", edad:23},
        {name: "pepe", edad:25}
    ];

    var persona = {};
    var unicos = personas.filter(function (e) { 
        return persona[e.name] ? false : (persona[e.name] = true);
    });

    console.log(unicos);
```

Answer (score -2):

Podrías hacerte un filter customizado para que te devuelva lo que necesites.
O incluso hacerte un `angular.forEach` e ir almacenandolos en un array al contrarlos mediante un `indexOf()`.

Comment: un angular.forEach no es lo mismo que un for? es decir, ganaria tiempo haciendolo asi?

Comment: Podrias hacerlo con un for perfectamente. Pero la logica de dentro sería igual.